# Sustituir espacios por caracteres

Tags: php

Por el momento me he podido apañar con esto:

```
 $link = "";
 $longitud = strlen($pais);

 for($i = 0; $i<$longitud;$i++){
     if($pais[$i] == ""){
         $link .= '+';
     }else{
         $link .= $pais[$i];
     }
 }
```

El resultado sería, por ejemplo, si `$pais = "Estados Unidos de America"` la variable `$link = "Estados+Unidos+de+America"`

Mi duda es: hay alguna función a la que le puedas indicar un delimitador y un carácter o cadena de caracteres para sustituir dicho delimitador tipo `explode()` pero indicando un carácter de sustitución

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es generar una URL puedes usar [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php).

Si lo que quieres es hacer algo como lo que hace Wordpress que es tener un `slug` puedes utilizar algo así:

`$slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);`

En esa función puedes seleccionar cual seria el "separador". Realmente la función [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) te da mucho juego